# Check if password input matches stored password, using Laravel 5.1

Tags: validation, laravel-5.1

once a user is logged into my application I want to give them the possibility to change their password. I have created three input fields (password_new, password_new_confirmation, password_old). In my form request I have the following rules but it doesn't work:

```
  $rules['password_new'] = 'required|confirmed|min:6';
  $rules['password_old'] = 'required|exists:users,password,email,'. Auth::user()->email;
```

This is perhaps because the password input is unhashed where as the stored password is in a hashed format?

So i'm thinking perhaps using the auth::validate facade as follows:

```
$valid = Auth::validate(['email' => Auth::user()->email, 'password' => Input::get('password_old')]);
if ( ! $valid)
{
    // add error to validator
}
```

My question is how do i add the error to the validator instance inside my form request to overide it - below is the validator instance?

```
protected function getValidatorInstance()
{
    $factory = $this->container->make(ValidationFactory::class);
    if (method_exists($this, 'validator')) {
        return $this->container->call([$this, 'validator'], compact('factory'));
    }
    return $factory->make(
        $this->all(), $this->container->call([$this, 'rules']), $this->messages(), $this->attributes()
    );
}
```

When you manually create a validator you can apply a after validation hook as follows so using below how do I overide the validation instance above:

```
$validator->after(function($validator) {
    if (!Auth::validate(['email' => Auth::user()->email, 'password' => $this->input('password_old')) {
         $validator->errors()->add('password_old', 'Invalid password');
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The op is asking for laravel 5.1 but for the people who are using laravel 6.x and above, a password validation rule is added that will do it.

Check [its documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-password)

simply add this rule to your validation rules :

> 'password' => 'password'

you can also specify the **authentication guard**:

> 'password' => 'password:api'

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I have changed my answer.

To check your password with manual validation you can do this:

```
$valid = $this->validate($request,[
    'email' => 'required|exists:users,email',
    'old_password' => 'required|exists:users,password'
]);
```

And to add your own custom validation message, open this file:

```
resources/lang/en/validation.php
```

Find these code:

```
'custom' => [
    'attribute-name' => [
        'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
    ],
],
```

Inside `custom` you can add your own validation messages. Example:

```
'custom' => [
    'email' => [
        'required' => 'You must give you Email address',
    ]
    'old_password' => [
        'exists' => 'Invalid password try again',
    ],
],
```

You can use `:attribute` instead of hard code the attribute name. Ex: `Invalid :attribute try again` or `You must give your :attribute address`

Hope this will help.

Comment: My questions is how to overide the validator instance so that I can add an error message to the field. See my updated post.

Comment: Do you want to create a custom error message for `password_old` field?

Comment: yes. i need a custom validation to check if password_old matches the one stored in database.

Comment: This is incorrect. Custom validation rule error messages should be placed in the first level of the array, not within the custom array according to the official docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: 'old_password' => 'required|exists:users,password', this rule will only work if passwords are stored in plain text and not hashed